How to determine if the SRT in the ISS of an Arm's Data Abort refers to the zero register or the Stack Pointer when it is set to 31?
In the Arm CPU spec, the instructions that deal with registers can either use the Stack Pointer (SP) or the Zero register (ZR).
When a data abort occurs, there is the SRT in ISS that shows the register the value is copied from or read into.
If the SRT is set to 31, I want to know if there is a specific field in the ISS or any other place that can be used to determine if it is referring to the ZR or the SP.
I found that I can use the DFSC & LST together to know if the instruction was from 4 possible instructions that use the Zero register, but if it didn't come from these instructions, is there another way to know?
